# Java screen scraper and on the fly DOM updater like jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, screen

jQuery has powerful on the fly DOM manipulation API like selector.html() gets the html of the specified selector and selector.html(replacement html) replaces html. I am looking for same thing but in Java.
Is there such a Java library? It should also be very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It has a an API inspired by jQuery and can handle most HTML pages you throw at it.